# How to prevent a window to load if it has not previously gone through the stage of login in Java?

Tags: java, authentication, jframe

I have made a program in **Java** that has two windows (JFrames):

a) The Log-in Window,

b) The Main Window.

The correct way to run the program is to run first the "Log-in Window" and if the username and password are correct, then this window redirects you to the "Main Window", making the "Log-in Window" to dispose.

**BUT**

If someone runs directly the "Main Window" (ignoring the Log-in stage), then this window will **run correctly without any authentication**...

**SO**

How can I prevent the "Main Window" from loading and running if someone runs it directly (e.g.`>> java Main_Window`)? I want my program to run **only** with the order (1) "Log-in Window" and then (2) "Main Window".

**EDIT**

The `Main_Window` class has only one `main` method with the below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      try {

        final Main_Window frame = new Main_Window();            
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            toRunOnClose();
            frame.dispose();
          }

        });

      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }

  });

}
```

Comment: don't put an entry point in your Main Window

Comment: do you have a `main` method in your Main Window class?

Comment: yes, of course I have a `main` method to be able to invoke the `run()` method and later the `Main_Window frame = new Main_Window();` and other code on loading and on closing this frame...

Comment: Please show pertinent code. Let's avoid guessing how many main methods your classes have.

Comment: So get rid of the `main` method inside of `Main_Window`. Have only one main method, the one that starts your login window -- which should be a modal dialog by the way, and that also opens your Main_Window if the dialog is successful.

Comment: If i remove the `main` method from `Main_Window` then how can I: 1) Run some code at the loading time of the main window, 2) How can i set the look and feel (later) without a main method and 3) How can I run some code when the frame closes (as i already doing now)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Your login window should be a **modal** dialog, such as a JDialog, not a JFrame.
- Your GUI should have only **one** main method, the method that calls your login modal dialog first, and then if successful, opens the main JFrame after this.

The main main method could look something like:

```
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      LoginDialog loginDialog = new LoginDialog();
      loginDialog.setVisible(true);

      // however you verify that the user is authentic
      if (loginDialog.verify()) {
         MainGui mainGui = new MainGui();
         mainGui.setVisible(true);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
```

In the example above, since LoginDialog is modal, the code below `loginDialog.setVisible(true)` is not run until the dialog window is no longer visible.

---

Regarding your questions:

> 1) Run some code at the loading time of the main window,

Run it in the single one main method.

> 2) How can i set the look and feel (later) without a main method

You'll have a main method, but only **one** main method.

> 3) How can I run some code when the frame closes (as i already doing now)?

Do the same thing but in a single main method.

Comment: Very good answer, I understand what you mean but I'm not familiar with `modal dialogs`. Plus, my `"Log-in Window"` class has a lot of code inside it (for authentication purposes and other checks).. Is there an easy way to convert the `"Log-in Window"` class to a modal dialog? Is it simple?

Comment: @MinimalTech: read the JDialog API as it's all there. Note that you should not have classes that extend JFrame or JDialog and that doing this will hamstring your code. Instead your GUI's should create JPanels, and then you can place these in your modal JDialogs or JFrames as the need arises.